# Youtube Studio - Ability to Get Financial Reports via Reporting API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Currently trying to figure out if we are able to get the Financial Reports (from Youtube Studio -> Reports Section -> Financial Reports Tab) such as Ads Revenue, Subscription Revenue, Transaction Revenue, Audio Tier Revenue, Paid Features, Shorts Revenue, Ads&Subscription Adjustments Revenue and so on via an API integration.

If anyones knows, could you also provide the YouTubes documentation that points this out.

FYI not looking for estimates but actual Financial Reports.

The only thing close I was able to find:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/sample-requests#content-owner-revenue-ads-reports
*Revenue and ad performance metrics for claimed content
This request retrieves revenue and ad performance metrics for the content owner's claimed content. The report returns a single row of data that contains totals for each requested metric during the specified date range.

metrics=views,estimatedRevenue,estimatedAdRevenue,estimatedRedPartnerRevenue,grossRevenue,adImpressions,cpm,playbackBasedCpm,monetizedPlaybacks
filters=claimedStatus==claimed*